# Replace random instance of substring inside a string (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I want to look for instances of a given substring inside a string, and replace it randomly: not in every instance of it, but only esporadically.
I was thinking of using the .each method for each instance of the substring, and then inside the code block using rand to replace it or not depending on the result.
But I am a bit stuck about how to implement the .each method in this situation. Can anyone help?
(I am using Ruby 1.9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use block-variant of `String#gsub`:

```
s = 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar'
# and you want to change random instances of "foo" with "baz":
s.gsub(/foo/){|m| rand(2) == 0 ? 'baz' : m}
#=> "baz bar foo bar baz bar foo bar"
```

Comment: Didn't know I can iterate with gsub. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

```
# this is original string
mystring = "some long string"
# this is given substring
substring = "some substring"
# this is raplace string (should be blank)
replace = "some substring replace"
# this is a loop
mystring.split(substring).inject{|new, chunk| new += (rand(2) == 0 ? substring : replace) + chunk }
```

For example:

```
mystring = "hello hello my dear friends! hello and goodbye after hello!"
substring = "hello"
replace = "pinky"
mystring.split(substring).inject{|new, chunk| new += (rand(2) == 0 ? substring : replace) + chunk }
#=> "hello pinky my dear friends! pinky and goodbye after hello!"
```

Comment: I dont really understand what is that doing. What does inject do, exactly? And what are the parameters it passes to the code block?