# Replace each string in turn in a ruby on rails loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I have the following string `'foo bar baz'`.

I want to loop over this string and remove a space each time so that I end up with:

```
foo bar baz
foobar baz
foo barbaz
```

I expect it has something to do with `gsub` as well as checking how many spaces there are so it knows how many times to loop over the string.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718895/1116573 might help but I've not quite got my head around how I need to apply it for my needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output you've given you could use the following (this only works in ruby >= 1.9) :

```
s = "foo bar baz"

s.chars.each_with_index do |ch, idx|
  if ch == ' '
    s1 = s.dup
    s1[idx] = ''
    puts s1
  end
end
```